# Can I return a Vue JS component in a callback method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Assume I have a method in a Vue.js component that returns a string to be rendered onto the page:

```
display: (arg) => {
    return arg.name
}
```

And in the relevant HTML:

```
<div html="component.display(arg)">
</div>
```

This has worked fine for me until now, but now I want to return HTML with some Vue-bound data on it:

```
display: (arg) => {
    return '<button @click="myMethod(arg)">Click</button>'
}
```

Obviously, the above doesn't work. My research has led me to believe that the correct approach here would be to create a component and return it, but I just can't seem to get it working. How would I approach this problem?

Comment: Your question is very confusing without knowing 1) What `arg` is and where it is defined. 2) What `component` is. 3) Where `myMethod` is defined

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're after is a [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

I would use a computed property to return the component definition to take advantage of Vue's reactivity (methods run all the time, computed properties only when required)

```
<component :is="display" :arg="arg" @click="myMethod"></component>
```

and...

```
computed: {
  display () {
    // you weren't clear on the conditions
    // that should cause this to return something different
    // but here is where you would put them
    return {
      props: ['arg'],
      template: `<button @click="$emit('click', arg)">Click</button>`
    }
  }
}
```

I'm assuming here that `myMethod` is defined in the *parent*, hence adding the `@click` handler on `<component>` and `$emit` in the child.

---

I suppose you could use a method to return the component definition but that feels like it would be quite inefficient and there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: This is way better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you could make that button its own component.

```
// New component
Vue.component('arg-button', {
  props: ['arg'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      arg: null
    }
  },
  myMethod: function(arg) {
    console.log(arg)
  },
  template: `
    <button 
      @click="myMethod(arg)">
        Click
    </button>`
})

// Old component
Vue.component('parent', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      arg: null,
      displayIfArg: true
    }
  },
  template: `
    <arg-button 
      v-show="displayIfArg"
      :arg="arg">
    </arg-button>`

})
```

---

Your overall approach is what Vue solves *without* returning functions-as-strings like that. There's a couple of ways to do it The Vue Way, but it roughly involves conditional instantiation/display of components—which should be readily reusable anyway, so thinking you need to base your return on `arg` *itself* is likely more hassle than it's worth.

Components should above all be reusable and atomic. Read their [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html), esp. on components, it'll shed a lot of light.

Comment: That's a fantastic explanation after your code. Hope it helps OP see things the _"Vue way"_

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a function that will return a component and be able to use vue-bound data but do not want to make that into a separate file, then you can look into [render functions in vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html)